# $_GET function not working for my wordpress website

Tags: php, html, wordpress, get

Here is the URL:

localhost/wordpress/?page_id=51.html?err=Please%20Enter%20your%20Password%20Confirmation

Here is the code that is not working:

```
<h2 class="site-description2">
        <?php if(isset($_GET["err"])) echo $_GET["err"]; ?>
</h2>
```

Thanks in advance. Appreciate all help.

Comment: I dont see any php file in that url

Comment: Whoa whoa whoa, XSS vulnerability here. NEVER output something directly from `POST` or `GET`. Run it through [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) first.  If you don't, people could use your site to attack one of your users. Do `echo htmlspecialchars($_GET["err"]);` instead.

Answer (score 2):

separate $_GET parameters with &

```
localhost/wordpress/?page_id=51.html&err=Please%20Enter%20your%20Password%20Confirmation
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much. Care to explain why ? didn't work?

Comment: It did not work because thats just not how they work in the first place: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string#Web_forms

Comment: query string starts with '?'. After that, each new GET parameter is separated using '&'